# multilevel menu item deletion recursion function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete category from multilevel menu with recursion function. To understand situation more carefully , lets take a look first at mysql table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p_id INT(5),
sort_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
);
```

it looks like this when it is retrieved

```
  id  |  p_id  |  sort_id  | title  |

   1  |    0   |     1     | root1  |
   2  |    1   |     1     |  sub of root1
   3  |    0   |     2     | root2  |
   4  |    2   |     1     |  sub of "sub of root1"
  ... |  ...   |    ...    |   ....
etc ...
```

I've written php script for delete category, here it is =>

```
function del_cat($connection,$id){
        if (!$connection->connect_errno){
        if ($connection->set_charset("utf8")){
            if ($r = $connection->query("SELECT id FROM menu WHERE p_id=" . $id . "")){
            if ($r->num_rows>0){
                while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                del_cat($connection,$row['id']);
                }
            } else {
                $connection->query("DELETE FROM menu WHERE id=" . $id . "");
            }
            $r->free();
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

`$connection` variable is a just mysql connection object, and `$id` is `id` in table.

It works just fine when I'm deleting one row ( I mean when category doesn't have a child , sub categories), for example `1  |    0   |     1     | root1  |`, but when I want to delete for example `4  |    2   |     1     |  sub of "sub of root1"` it doesn't delete category with sub categories . Any idea how to solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: If you've got a foreign key relationship in that table with cascaded deletes, mysql would take care of deleting the child records for you.

Comment: @MarcB I amn't using foreign keys

Comment: @MarcB this is exactly same table in which I'm trying to make this action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete is only in `else` so you never actually delete the parent category.  I think you need something like:

```
   del_cat($connection, $row['id']);
   $connection->query("DELETE ...");
} else {
   $connection->query("DELETE ...");
```

By the way you should escape the ID input.